# Can't change input value due to value variable

Tags: reactjs, use-state

When my page loads I load some data, which updates a `useState` hook, i.e:

```
const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState()
```

I then use the value to fill out an input field like:

```
<input type="number" value={inputVal} onChange={(e) => setInputVal(e.target.value)} />
```

But this doesn't seem to work. It locks the first-load value, and I can't write/change anything in my input field.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Maybe initialize default value 0. For example usestate(0)

Comment: What error/warning your console says?

Comment: What type of inputs are you trying to give?

Comment: Can u provide  Codesandbox?

Comment: @OsmanysFuentes-Lombá this one: "Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`."

Comment: @NijatAliyev it already has a default value, so I don't think it's that.

Comment: @DenverDang this error:  "Warning: You provided a value prop to a form field without an onChange handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use defaultValue. Otherwise, set either onChange or readOnly." throw only when the onChange event is not handled but in your sample code there is a handler for the event, son I'm asking you: what error/warning says the console after handled the onChange event?

Comment: Okey, now check both state and input includes in the same function or must be connection between

Comment: @OsmanysFuentes-Lombá the thing is, that since I can't change the value in my input field, the onChange event is not triggered (it seems). So I don't know any other warnings/errors after the initial load giving me the error above.